# Apple Music Songs - MPMusicPlayerController giving wrong playbackState

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, apple-music

As Apple said in **iOS 9.3** we can [Access Apple Music Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9_3.html). I am playing it from my application by `MPMusicPlayerController`.

I am getting wrong playbackState. For Ex. If  song continue playing - so it should return status `MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying` but gettting other enum values. My code is

```
 if ([[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] playbackState]==MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
            {
            }
            else
            {
 NSLog(@"playbackState %ld",(long)[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] playbackState]);
             }
```

As apple saying [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMusicPlaybackState) we have following possible vales -

```
Values for the playbackState property.
Declaration

Objective-C

enum {
   MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped,
   MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying,
   MPMusicPlaybackStatePaused,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateSeekingForward,
   MPMusicPlaybackStateSeekingBackward 
};
typedef NSInteger MPMusicPlaybackState;
```

How will I get the correct state of current playing song . Any Idea, If I mistaken something please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is insane but this works:

```
_ = systemMusicPlayer.currentPlaybackRate        
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { [weak self] in
    print(self?.systemMusicPlayer.playbackState)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced this issue. So the workaround is: every n seconds check the `[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] currentPlaybackRate]` property. 1 corresponds to "playing" and 0 to "paused" (or stopped).

Comment: Does not help with iOS 12. It reports the same wrong status as `playbackState`